# What is mean a valid name as a DNS name component?

Tags: image, docker, deployment, dns

I write command :
`docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml testlogin/test` and get this error - `Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 3 desc = name must be valid as a DNS name component`

What name is considered valid?

Comment: FQDN? localhost.domain?

Comment: I use this ```sudo docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml docker_login_id/image_name``` For example I insert ``` testlogin/test```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, the name of the stack is invalid. This is likely due to the `/` in the name.

Answer (score 0):

The stack name may contain spaces or other special characters.